NextJS 15 + Shadcn ui: Menu disappears when user logged in
My Navbar.tsx component looks like this:
import Link from "next/link"

import { Menu } from "lucide-react"

import NavbarLogo from "@/components/commons/NavbarLogo"
import SignIn from "@/components/commons/SignIn"
import UserAccountNav from "@/components/commons/UserAccountNav"
import ViewportWrapper from "@/components/commons/ViewportWrapper"
import ThemeToggle from "@/components/theme/theme-toggle"
import { Button, buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
    Sheet,
    SheetClose,
    SheetContent,
    SheetFooter,
    SheetHeader,
    SheetTitle,
    SheetTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/sheet"

import brand from "@/lib/constants/brand.json"

// Define a more specific type for the session
type Session = {
    user?: {
        name?: string | null
        image?: string | null
    } | null
}

const NAV_LINKS = [
    {
        href: "/about",
        label: "About",
        ariaLabel: "About our services",
    },
    {
        href: "/discover",
        label: "Discover",
        ariaLabel: "Discover our services",
    },
    { href: "/pricing", label: "Pricing", ariaLabel: "View pricing options" },
]

const Navbar = ({ session }: { session: Session | null }) => {
    const user = session?.user

    return (
        // Main navigation container
        <nav
            className="sticky h-14 inset-x-0 top-0 z-30 w-full border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-800 bg-white/70 dark:bg-black/75 backdrop-blur-lg transition-all"
            aria-label="Main navigation"
        >
            <ViewportWrapper>
                <div className="flex h-14 items-center justify-between border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-800">
                    {/* Brand Logo */}
                    <div className="flex items-center">
                        <Sheet>
                            <SheetTrigger asChild>
                                {/* Add md:hidden to hide <Menu> icon on desktop */}
                                <Button
                                    variant="outline"
                                    size="icon"
                                    className="mr-2"
                                >
                                    <Menu />
                                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle menu</span>
                                </Button>
                            </SheetTrigger>
                            <SheetContent side="left">
                                <SheetHeader>
                                    <SheetTitle>{brand.BRAND}</SheetTitle>
                                </SheetHeader>
                                <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
                                    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
                                        <p>test</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
                                        <p>test 2</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <SheetFooter>
                                    <SheetClose asChild>
                                        <Button type="submit">
                                            Save changes
                                        </Button>
                                    </SheetClose>
                                </SheetFooter>
                            </SheetContent>
                        </Sheet>
                        <Link
                            href="/"
                            className="flex z-40 font-semibold gap-2 items-center"
                        >
                            <NavbarLogo />
                            <span className="text-lg text-soft dark:text-white/70">
                                {brand.BRAND}
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    {/* TODO: Add mobile navbar */}

                    {/* Desktop Navigation Links */}
                    <div className="hidden items-center space-x-4 sm:flex">
                        {NAV_LINKS.map(({ href, label, ariaLabel }) => (
                            <Link
                                key={href}
                                href={href}
                                className={buttonVariants({
                                    variant: "link",
                                    size: "sm",
                                    className: "dark:text-primary/90",
                                })}
                                aria-label={ariaLabel}
                            >
                                {label}
                            </Link>
                        ))}

                        {/* Theme Toggle */}
                        <ThemeToggle />

                        {/* Conditional User Navigation or Sign-In */}
                        {!user ? (
                            <SignIn aria-label="Sign in to your account" />
                        ) : (
                            <UserAccountNav
                                name={user.name ?? "No name"}
                                image={user.image ?? ""}
                                aria-label={`User account navigation for ${
                                    user.name || "anonymous user"
                                }`}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ViewportWrapper>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar

As you can tell, I have a  icon as a toggle for the Shadcn  component. When the button is clicked, the  slides in from the left. This works fine when the user is logged out. But the moment you log in (by clicking the Sign in with X button), the  element disappears. I have no hidden attribute on the  element. What could I be doing wrong?
If I remove the  element completely and just keep the  element next to the logo  element, it shows fine in all situations.
The repo is up at https://github.com/schandillia/project-pico.
The deployment is up at https://project-pico.vercel.app/.
